# Git is very slow on Mac / OSX

Tags: git, macos, github, atlassian-sourcetree

Whenever I use anything Git related on my Macbook (Brand-new Macbook Pro with El Capitan), it takes almost a full minute for each command. I did a simple

> GIT_TRACE=1 git stash

and got back this:

```
17:04:27.460826 git.c:557               trace: exec: 'git-stash'
17:04:27.463136 run-command.c:347       trace: run_command: 'git-stash'
17:04:32.503827 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--git-dir'
17:04:34.521223 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--show-toplevel'
17:04:35.527473 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-colorbool' 'color.interactive'
17:04:36.534443 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' 'color.interactive.help' 'red bold'
17:04:37.538357 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'config' '--get-color' '' 'reset'
17:04:38.544472 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'update-index' '-q' '--refresh'
17:04:39.567521 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'diff-index' '--quiet' '--cached' 'HEAD' '--ignore-submodules' '--'
17:04:40.578480 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'diff-files' '--quiet' '--ignore-submodules'
17:04:41.595078 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'update-index' '-q' '--refresh'
17:04:42.612776 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'diff-index' '--quiet' '--cached' 'HEAD' '--ignore-submodules' '--'
17:04:43.621067 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'diff-files' '--quiet' '--ignore-submodules'
17:04:44.636720 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'rev-parse' '--verify' 'HEAD'
17:04:45.642275 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'rev-list' '--oneline' '-n' '1' 'HEAD' '--'
17:04:46.648038 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'symbolic-ref' '-q' 'HEAD'
17:04:47.653633 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'write-tree'
17:04:48.664282 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'commit-tree' '<hex_number>' '-p' '<hex_number>'
17:04:49.672125 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'read-tree' '--index-output=/Users/<USER>/.git/index.stash.62412' '-m' '<hex_number>'
17:04:50.707740 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'diff' '--name-only' '-z' 'HEAD' '--'
17:04:51.737890 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'update-index' '-z' '--add' '--remove' '--stdin'
17:04:52.752634 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'write-tree'
17:04:53.772245 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'commit-tree' '<hex_number>' '-p' '<hex_number>' '-p' '<hex_number>'
17:04:54.778991 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'update-ref' '-m' 'WIP on <branch>: <hex_number> <branch> Kept working for a bit' 'refs/stash' '<hex_number>'
Saved working directory and index state WIP on <branch>: <hex_number> <branch> Kept working for a bit
17:04:55.787801 git.c:348               trace: built-in: git 'reset' '--hard'
HEAD is now at <hex_number> <branch> Kept working for a bit
```

I'm primarily using Atlassian's SourceTree, but the problem also persists on the git command-line (also, so is the log I showed). Our source for hosting the code is MULTIPLE paid, private repos on Github.com.

Is there anything that I can try to speed up git operations? It doesn't seem to matter which operation it is, they are ALL slow.

Thanks in advance. Also, sorry if this isn't the right spot for this question. :)

Comment: Probably a better fit for [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com). What version of git? Do you have Time Machine set to watch the working copies?

Comment: I just posted it there. The latest version of git (I just got the machine a few weeks ago) and no, Time Machine is not set up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the problem. It was my antivirus. WebRoot was screwing it all up. I have a support ticket in to them for what to do, but for now I've disabled it.

Comment: Same problem here, WebRoot SecureAnywhere installed and SourceTree/Git grind to a halt. Did you find a fix?

Comment: WebRoot says they're "working on it".... But I've just had it disabled since I figured it out.

Comment: Cool thanks... that's exactly what I've done too. It cost me £25 or so....... money well spent!

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem myself, and it was affecting all commands (e.g. git and python). It was being caused by Malwarebytes. Opened a support ticket.