# Git clone is incredibly slow on my Mac. How can I fix that?

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I googled a lot about this problem, but couldn't find any good answer.

On my Mac, git clone from a Github repository literally takes ages. I have a 16mbit connection, but the typical download rates from Github are about 50k, which is just ridiculous.

It doesn't matter whether the download is triggered via Github Desktop client or via command line, they behave just the same.

Only in very rare cases, the download speeds up to an acceptable rate. But in most cases, I can drink coffee while waiting for the download to finish. This is especially annoying since I often download large Cordova plugins with a lot of native code. This sometimes takes 20-30 minutes...

Any ideas how to tackle this problem? Thanks.

Comment: If you put another machine in your network and try it with that, does it make a difference?

Comment: I've tried to download one of the repos with my Windows machine. There, the download rates are acceptable (700-800k/s). Should be ~1.8mb/s for a 16mbit connection, but at least that's much better than on the Mac.

Comment: So it could be a networking configuration issue on your mac.

Comment: You might find some useful info on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927403/git-is-very-slow-on-mac-osx

Answer (score 0):

First is your repo big? Do you save bin files? are you using git lfs?

Did you try GIT_TRACE?
[Debugging Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#Debugging)
Try set the following environment variables:

```
GIT_TRACE=1
GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=1
GIT_TRACE_SETUP=1
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1
```

Secondly, You can try github debug:
https://github-debug.com/

It will run some tests, then you can copy the results and open a ticket.

**You will complete the following steps:**

1. Run the commands for your corresponding operating system.

```
    git clone https://github.com/github/debug-repo /tmp/debug-repo-http
    git clone git@github.com:github/debug-repo /tmp/debug-repo-ssh
    ping -c 10 github.com
    traceroute github.com
    curl -s -o/dev/null -w "downloadspeed: %{speed_download} | dnslookup: %{time_namelookup} | connect: %{time_connect} | appconnect: %{time_appconnect} | pretransfer: %{time_pretransfer} | starttransfer: %{time_starttransfer} | total: %{time_total} | size: %{size_download}\n" https://github.com
```

2. Run the tests and wait for results.
   [test](https://github-debug.com/)
3. Finally, copy & paste the results from your local commands and the above tests into a message for our [Support Team](https://support.github.com/contact?form%5Bsubject%5D=Re:%20GitHub%20Debug%20Results).