# git commands taking a long time for newer repos

Tags: git

For some reason my git takes a long time to execute most commands on newer repos. This started with clone and pull (~5 min to pull a 6 byte change) but also extends to add and commit. I initially thought this might be an issue with large binary files or previously committed files in the history but this issue also persists with brand new repos. Additionally, my git works fine with repos older than a week. I've had other people try cloning the same repos and everything works fine for them. The version of git also doesn't seem to be the cause either as I've tried both the default Apple git and the most recent version of git. I've also tried with a blank .gitconfig with no success.

Comment: What exact Mac OS version are you using?

Comment: Currently using 10.12.6

Comment: Hmm I'm also on a 10.12.6.. and if you say "_everything works fine_" for other people, then it's likely an env issue. Have you tried doing a `git gc`? Do you have any git bash prompts installed? (I'm assuming here you're using git from command line.) It can also be an antivirus issue, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927403/git-is-very-slow-on-mac-osx).

Comment: I definitely believe this is an env issue, but I just have no idea where the issue is.

I have tried `git gc` in the past but nothing changed.

By git bash prompts, do you mean something like a git wrapper (e.g. hub)? If so, I do use hub but I still experience the issue without it installed.

Also, while antivirus is a possibility, I doubt it's the root cause as the people who helped me before by cloning the repos that gave me issues have the exact same antivirus setup.